# ValidateAntiForgeryToken Equivalent for ASMX Web Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, extjs

We have an MVC web application that has multiple web technologies including a portion with numerous extJs Post requests that call into an asmx web service. The web service methods are decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute. In MVC we are able to use the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute and append the csrf token the client side .ajax post. Is there a similar attribute that we could append to the Web Service(asmx) methods to get HP Fortify to stop complaining?

Comment: Interesting. Unfamiliar with HPFortify, assuming its app firewall. What is it complaining about? re: by the time it's involved, it seems(?) the request was already spawned (so a bit unclear)....

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?